# undefined method `post_id' with post as a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, so I am currently working on a commenting system where posts belong to classrooms and posts have comments. So classrooms have comments through posts.

Here are the models

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
...
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
...
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  has_many :comments
...
end
```

I'm trying to save post_ids but it won't let me with a simple hidden field so I tried it with a value and it still doesn't work. it says that post_id is an undefined method.

Here is my classroom controller's show method because it is where the new comment form is being rendered.

```
def show
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @classroom.posts
    @comments =  @classroom.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

Here is the new comment form.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @classroom.post_id  %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error Message
**NoMethodError in Classrooms#show
undefined method `post_id' for Classroom:0x007f52aa646b18**

How do I save the post_id? 
Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that you have reverted the acceptance on my answer. May I know the reason please?

Comment: Must've accidently double clicked, I also upvoted it and that's still there but accepting the answer isn't. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NoMethodError in Classrooms#show undefined method `post_id' for
>   Classroom:0x007f52aa646b18

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @classroom.post_id  %>
```

The error is obvious as you are doing `@classroom.post_id` as `Classroom` don't have a field called `post_id`

Define a `@post` with the help of `@classroom`

```
def show
  @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  @post = Post.where(classroom_id: @classroom.id).first
  @posts = @classroom.posts
  @comments =  @classroom.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

and use that in the `hidden_field`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

Comment: I tried @post.id, and things like that and I needed to associate comments with classrooms so they would appear, so I'm not sure what else to try or how to define post id in the classroom controller.